# Django REST Framework: Provide QuerySet to Renderer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

We would like to use the Django REST framework to render the model data (with the filtering specified via the Django REST framework API) as plots. Our plotting engine directly works with Django `QuerySets`.

The question is: How is it possible serialize the model data as Django `QuerySets`?

We've tried to create a Serializer that simply passes on the data (with no success):

```
class QuerySetSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    many = True
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj
```

It would be great if it was possible to access the same `QuerySet` via the Django REST Framework (with `<my filter>` arguments supplied via the Django REST Framework URL system) that you would access internally with

```
mymodel.objects.filter(<my filter>)
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I do not understand how you'd like to transfer data. You do not want to serialize it as JSON?

Comment: Exactly. I would like for the `Renderer` to have access to the `QuerySet` instance which corresponds to the API query. (The `Renderer` can then do whatever it wants with the `QuerySet` - in my case invoke a method on the `QuerySet` that will create a Plot as .png). (See my comment to @jape also - hope it's clearer?)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean doing something like this?

```
from rest_framework import generics, serializers

from .models import Foo


class QuerySetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id', 'field1', 'field2',)


class QuerySetList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuerySetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Foo.objects.filter(<my filter>)  # You can filter whatever you want here
```

Comment: An example of what I would like: Let's say there is a Django model Person with attributes name and email. Through the API, I could access all Person instances with a certain name as follows: `/api/?name=John`. Instead of creating e.g. json from these instances, I'd like to have access to the Person QuerySet (within the Renderer). This should equal to what you get with `Person.objects.filter(name=John)`. So my Q is: when an arbitrary API url `/api/?name=John` is accessed, how do I provide the corresponding QuerySet to the Renderer. (Is this more clear now? I can update my above Q if in case?)